# TSLint apply multiple rules for whitespace

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have the following rule in tslint.json

```
"whitespace": [true, "check-decl", "check-operator", "check-separator", "check-type"]
```

I would also like to add this:

```
"whitespace": [false, "check-branch"]
```

Is this possible? and if so how do i add it?